# How to get Basic Info About Yourself Beneath your Site's Search Result?

Tags: html, seo, microdata, json-ld, google-schemas

Link to Elon Musk's Wikipedia Search Results:

[image: Link to Elon Musk's Wikipedia Search Results:]

So, I have a Website about Myself, Nothing Fancy, Thought that it would be a good way to learn Googles SEO.

Now, I want my Search Result Description to have some Basic Info About Myself.

As you can see, When You Search for Elon Musk's Wikipedia, Some Basic Info About Elon Musk have been Given, Like his Citizenship, Parents, Title Etc. Beneath the Description.
I want my sites search results to also have something like this.
I am not talking about the Description of the site like

```html
<meta name="description" content="Description" />
```

I am talking about Markups like JSON-LD, Microdata, vCard, etc. I have tried JSON-LD, vCard, microdata but, It doesn't work, I have also tried all sorts of validators including Googles own Markup Validator and, the code works,

And

```json
{"@type": "Person"}
```

doesn't change anything.

I have seen that not only Wikipedia but, some other sites can also do this. I am not using any generator. And the site is on GitHub pages.

And My JSON-LD code looks like this, If you can help me about It, I would be grateful.
I hope I have given enough details.

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "Article",
  "name": "x y z",
  "url": "Website",
  "mainEntityOfPage": {
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "@id": "Website"
  },
  "headline": "My Name",
  "keywords": "Keywords",
  "description": "Description",
  "articleBody": "Body",
  "image": {
    "@type": "ImageObject",
    "url": "/img/private/Bonjour.jpg",
    "width": "517",
    "height": "517"
  },
  "author": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "x y z",
    "email": "x@gmail.com"
  },
  "datePublished": "2021-06-12",
  "dateModified": "2021-08-05",
  "about": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "email": "x@gmail.com",
    "name": "x y z",
    "alternateName": "alternate name",
    "givenName": "x",
    "familyName": "y",
    "additionalName": "z",
    "owns": [
      {
        "@type": "Website",
        "url": "Website"
      }
    ],
    "nationality": "Bangladeshi",
    "jobTitle": "Student",
    "birthDate": "2004-09-09",
    "weight": "60",
    "height": "70",
    "gender": "Male",
    "knowsLanguage": [
      "en",
      "en-US",
      "bn",
      "hi"
    ],
    "description": "Description.",
    "alumniOf": [
      {
        "@type": "Organization",
        "name": "x Elementary School",
        "sameAs": "Schools Site"
      }
    ],
    "image": [
      {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "/img/private/Bonjour.jpg",
        "width": "517",
        "height": "517"
      },
      {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "/img/private/Devil.jpg",
        "width": "1138",
        "height": "1138"
      },
      {
        "@type": "ImageObject",
        "url": "/img/private/Rooftop-Candid.jpg",
        "width": "408",
        "height": "408"
      }
    ],
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "addressLocality": "My City",
      "postalCode": "4000",
      "addressCountry": "Country"
    },
    "birthPlace": {
      "@type": "Place",
      "address": {
        "@type": "PostalAddress",
        "addressLocality": "City",
        "postalCode": "4000",
        "addressCountry": "Country"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: In order for a site to display rich result, it must be on the first result on google search. You can test this on https://search.google.com/test/rich-results
Also it takes time for Google to update the search result. Therefore, your code might already work.

Comment: My webpage is on the first when you search for my real name, I have also seen that many sites even on second page of google has it, like brittanica, when you search for a well known person, Wikipedia comes before brittanica, still brittanica contains General data about said person beneath their description, and I have used the rich-results and I have 0 errors, and I changed my json-ld code 10 days ago, while my last google index is 5 days ago, Google is such a pain when it comes to these matters.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question for the reasons described in the description of the [tag:seo] tag.